# Modify sub nav output using a filter in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to add html after the contents(sub-nav toggle button) in the li in my wordpress nav if the item has children...

I've tried using nav_menu_link_attributes and wp_nav_menu_args but can't seem to have either do what I want, because I need to check the class and modify the args.

Answer (score 0):

After not receiving a response I just used jquery to select the elements and append. Not quite the best solution, but works fine. Here is the line of code:

```
$('#site-nav .menu-item-has-children').append('<div class="sub-menu-toggle" id="sub-menu-toggle"><a href="#" class="sub-menu-toggle-icon">Menu</a></div>');
```